# Dealing with php xml posts and batching

Tags: php, mysql, batch-file

So I have a server with a PHP script that is going to get bombarded with xml posts. each xml could have 1 block of data or several blocks of data, the servers that are posting to me have variable timeouts of around 10seconds, so my script has about 10 seconds to tell their server that is got the stuff (http:200/page finished loading) or they will reattempt the post diving the system into a loop. my turnaround time needs to be almost instant as the emails and calls and such that will be sent due to this xml must be sent as soon as possible.

I have thought about doing the following: dump the xml into a txt file and record a log in the DB, thus the file will always respond within 10 seconds to the xml poster. Then have a job in the background processing the files. Someone suggested in another thread doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ "true" ]; do
        /path/to/script.php
        sleep 3
done
```

My issue is if I get 40 batch jobs that are large and 20 small ones, then over a period of a minute I could have 30 script.php instances running. I want to make the batch script run and when its done launch the next batch script and so one without causing memory issues.

so would it be better to do the following:

processor.php:

```
<?php
select next record sort by date desc
grab file, process it
header location to same script
?>
```

if there is no record then maybe sleep 3, so the page is always being run, and I have a cron checking that it is active to restart should something go wrong. But will this cause a men issue, or when it header locations to itself it resets the memory?

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a decent plan, how about:

receiver.php

```
//Receive XML
//Option 1: Store in text file (with timestamp in name)
//  or
//Option 2: Store in text file and then store timestamped reference in database
//Respond to caller
```

processor.php (activated every 10 seconds or whatever via cron)

```
//Option 1: Check for new XML text files - grab the one with the oldest timestamp
//Option 2: Check database for oldest unprocessed XML - grab the referenced XML file
//Process XML
//Remove XML text file (& any reference in a database)
//Go back to the start of the processor.php script  (while loop or something that checks for unprocessed XML files)
```

Comment: Loop will result in page failing due to memory, So I need to know if header location back to same page will dump memory which will work for me

Comment: I would assume that using a HTTP header redirect to "refresh" the script would free up the memory as it's a completely new request. But, if you're managing memory throughout the script, you shouldn't have any memory issues I wouldn't think. E.g. using `unset()` to clear out any result sets and temporary storage of XML, etc.

Comment: would it not be better to use a cron running every 3 seconds to run processor.php, this allows for processing multiple xml files at same time

Comment: and if it is if I have 60 processor.php files processing a different xml each, if 2 try and update tbl in db, will one get dropped

Comment: As you say, it all depends on what the processing is the happens with each XML file. If the processing of 2 files at once might cause data integrity issues in the database, you're better doing it sequentially. Can you give an insight to the actual processing of the XML?

Comment: I implemented your plan as suggested, works fine. thank you for you help

Comment: Great!  :)  Which method did you end up using? Are you able to post any details?  :)